# mysqld: unrecognized service after installing Percona mySQL

Tags: mysql, percona

Fresh cloud server running Centos6. Trying to install latest Percona

```
$ sudo rpm -Uhv http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/percona-release-0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum install Percona-Server-server-56
$ sudo yum install Percona-Server-client-56

... installs

$ sudo service mysqld start

mysqld: unrecognized service
```

Have I missed something out ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, Percona installs as the `mysql` service, not `mysqld`.

Comment: Doh. Must be the late hour. Cheers!